# How to Get all information from table 2 by filtering a column value from table 1 without joining able (if possible)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Let's assume there's two table Table 1(only 1 column with ID 1,3,5,6,8) and table two (multiple columns; one of them being similar to table 1)

1. Id of table2 which can have any number of values (let's assume any 10 random numbers)
2. I'm only concerned about values that are equal to table1 ID
3. I want to check the missing ID in table 2 which are not present in table 2 but present in table 1.
4. I want to select all columns of table2 + the missing attribute
   Eg:

| TABLE1 | TABLE2 |
| --- | --- |
| ID. | ID Account name |
| 1 | 1 ABC |
| 3 | 5 ABC |
| 5 | 6 ABC |
| 6 | 19 ABC |
| 8 |  |

What I want in return as output is

| ID | Account name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | ABC |
| 8 | ABC |

Yes account names and other column values for table 2 would be all the same

And I want to do it without an inner query (if possible). I'm running out of ideas on how to achieve this

Comment: Please check the expected output because you mentioned you want IDs that are present in Table 1 but not in table 2. However ID 6 has been present in expected output.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over 2 years, it's long past time you sort out that upgrade plan.

Comment: Why are `3` and `6` in the expected output? How does `ABC` get into the row with `8` if there is no matching `Table2` row? What does this have to do with LINQ, and if you want to do it in LINQ what does it have to do with SQL?

Comment: @Arun that Was a mistake, removed it